# WPF Xaml - match width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment

I have the following `xaml`, where you can see a `GroupBox` on top and other ones on the left and on the right.
Is there a way to set the `GroupBox` on top so that (*when I resize the window*) its left and right edges are aligned respectively with the left edge of the GroupBoxes on the left and the right edge of the GroupBoxes on the right?

Edit

I'm keeping fixed the width of the groupboxes in the tab controls because I've implemented a wpf zooming there: I've updated the xaml now (of course the zoom is implemented also in the code behind)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="MatchWidth.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MatchWidth"
    Height="1000"
    Width="1600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <GroupBox
            Header="Top Box"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="25,5,35,25" />
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform
                    CenterX="0" CenterY="0"
                    ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSliderL,Path=Value}"
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSliderL,Path=Value}"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="5" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TabControl
                Name="LeftTabCtr"
                Grid.Column="0">
                <TabItem Header="LeftTabCtr">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Grid
                            Height="800">
                            <Slider
                                x:Name="uiScaleSliderL"
                                ToolTip="Determines the UI scale factor."
                                Value="1" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="4" Width="200" Height="10"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <GroupBox
                                Header="Left Box 1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="25,20,25,25"
                                Width="720"
                                Height="180"/>
                            <GroupBox
                                Header="Left Box 2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="720"
                                Margin="25,220,25,10" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
            <GridSplitter
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <TabControl
                Name="RightTabCtr"
                Grid.Column="2">
                <TabItem Header="RightTabCtr">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <Grid
                            Height="800">            <Slider
                                x:Name="uiScaleSliderR"
                                ToolTip="Determines the UI scale factor."
                                Value="1" Minimum="0.1" Maximum="4" Width="200" Height="10"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <GroupBox
                                Header="Right Box 1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="25,20,25,25"
                                Width="720"
                                Height="180"/>
                            <GroupBox
                                Header="Right Box 2"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="720"
                                Margin="25,220,25,10" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind contains something like that:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        uiScaleSliderL.MouseDoubleClick +=
            new MouseButtonEventHandler(RestoreScalingFactorL);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseWheel(args);
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) ||
            Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
            uiScaleSliderL.Value += (args.Delta > 0) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(args);
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) ||
            Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
        {
            if (args.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                RestoreScalingFactorL(uiScaleSliderL, args);
            }
        }
    }
    void RestoreScalingFactorL(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        ((Slider)sender).Value = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify correct margins and remove constant widths of groupboxes (maybe in your case it will be more flexibile to use minWidth, or just remove it completely)

Comment: You still can use your zooming content inside of groupboxes, just set the needed size to controls but not to Groupbox itself(or maybe put it inside grid with custom width) but let groupboxes be non constant width

Comment: Just dont get something - to what controls applies this zoom mechanism? and can you wrap the controls with zoom into viewBox?